# Find out how many concurrent touch points are supported on Windows 8 device

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, touch, multi-touch

For a Windows 8 App, is there a way to programmatically check how many concurrent touch points are supported by a device?

There are some devices (e.g. Samsung Ativ, WinRT) which only allow for five concurrent touch points. For a project I'm working on I need to have at least ten concurrent touch points, so I'd like to check for these cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [TouchCapabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br225644.aspx), there's [TouchPresent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.input.touchcapabilities.touchpresent.aspx) to determine if touch is, well, present :) and then [Contacts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.input.touchcapabilities.contacts.aspx) gives you the number of points.

For HTML5/JavaScript apps there's also: [msMaxTouchPoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779855.aspx)

See also the [Input: Device Capabilities Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Input-device-capabilities-31b67745)